# Regular Expression Parse Double

Tags: java

I am new to regular expressions. I want to search for `NUMBER(19, 4)`         and the method should return the value(in this case `19,4`). But I always get `0` as result !

```
       int length =0;
       length = patternLength(datatype,"^NUMBER\\((\\d+)\\,\\s*\\)$","NUMBER");

    private static double patternLengthD(String datatype, String patternString, String startsWith) {
        double length=0;
        if (datatype.startsWith(startsWith)) {
            Pattern patternA = Pattern.compile(patternString);
            Matcher matcherA = patternA.matcher(datatype);
                if (matcherA.find()) {
                    length = Double.parseDouble(matcherA.group(1)); 
            }
        }
        return length;
    }
```

Comment: Your pattern is "NUMBER" followed by `(`, followed by digits, followed by comma, followed by spaces. But you are trying to match something which has things that are not spaces after the comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the matching of digits after the comma.
You also don't need to escape the `,`.
Use this:

```
"^NUMBER\\((\\d+),\\s*(\\d+)\\)$"
```

This will give you the first number in `group(1)` and the second number in `group(2)`.

It is however fairly strict on spaces, so you can be more lenient and match on values like `" NUMBER ( 19 , 4 ) "` by using this:

```
"^\\s*NUMBER\\s*\\(\\s*(\\d+)\\s*,\\s*(\\d+)\\s*\\)\\s*$"
```

In that case you'll have to drop your `startsWith` and just use the regex directly. Also, you can remove the anchors (`^$`) if you change `find()` to `matches()`.

Since `NUMBER(19)` is usually allowed too. You can make the second value optional:

```
"\\s*NUMBER\\s*\\(\\s*(\\d+)\\s*(?:,\\s*(\\d+)\\s*)?\\)\\s*"
```

`group(2)` will then return `null` if the second number is not given.

See [regex101 for demo](https://regex101.com/r/uF7fS7/1).

---

Note that your code doesn't compile.
Your method returns a `double`, but `length` is an `int`.

Although `19,4` looks like a floating point number, it is not, and representing it as such is wrong.
You should store the two values separately.

Comment: thanks for the regex101.com website! This is a great help!